# Get best access response time from a server directory C#

Tags: c#, httprequest, response-time

My scenario is:

I've 20 servers:

```
\\server1.com
\\server2.com
\\server3.com

...

\\server20.com
```

My application need access the "best" server. "The best" means the one with the smallest response time.

How I can check this response time in C#?

Comment: With no details of what you are trying to access, how do you expect a response. For a Rest API use Postman to figure out exact duration of the request or just ping to find the best server

Comment: Asynchronously send a request to each and measure the total time for a response. Then use the one with the smallest time between sending the request and receiving the response. If you want more details then you have to provide some code and details on the protocol you are using to communicate with the servers.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I want to check the smallest response to access an directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate response time using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
timer.Stop();
TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

Comment: How do you know its a WebRequest ?